# downloading multiple images

Tags: iphone, interface

I want to download 3 images from 3 different urls and display them in the UI in iphone using Objective-c.

Some sample codes will be of great help.

Comment: I mean i want to download 3 images from 3 different urls and display them in the UI in iphone using objective c.Some sample codes will be of great help

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To download image you can

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://xxx.com/imageName.jpg"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImage *img = [[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data] autorelease];
```

Also you need to see Apple's LazyTableImages. You find a good example [here](http://www.markj.net/iphone-asynchronous-table-image/).

Comment: If you are going to download more than 1 image at a time, consider using a thread or multiple threads to do so.

Comment: Thanx a lot Maulik.. But actually i need to download and display more than one image in my ui. Any help is greately appreciated.

Comment: you can see the link I have mentioned.

Comment: Thanx Maulik, it really helped me. But how can we display the images in a plain UIView not in table? I mean how will we specify the urls one after another?

Comment: on your UIView add the UIImageView and put the image into the UIImageView .

Comment: OK... actually i got a single url image displayed in my ui.. How can i download multiple urls?is there something like an array to store the urls and then add them to uiimageview?

Comment: yes you can store images that you get from url into the NSArray or NSMutableArray then you can use it accordingly.

Comment: i want to download 3 images from 3 different urls and display them in the UI in iphone. foe one image it is working fine. what to do for 3?